# Camera rotation within a prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, quaternions, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to create a multiplayer game in unity3d using a diablo like camera system. So wherever I click on the screen. The system it was working fine in singleplayer where I did not need to include a camera in a player prefab. However Now I am facing the problem where my camera rotation is also affected by the rotation of my prefab parent. The hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

There is a script added to the camera that looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MainCameraComponent : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Reaper;
private Vector3 offset;


void Start () {
    offset = transform.position - Reaper.transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate () {
    transform.position = Reaper.transform.position + offset;
}
}
```

When I run the game the camera always stays behind my character, while I want it to always stay at the same rotation. so if I order my character to walk north I would see his back, if it would walk south I wanted to see the front.

[image]
[image]

notice how the shadow changes, (thus the rotation) but i always face the back of my model. TLDR: I want my child camera to ignore the rotational change of its parent and be static. whilst letting my camera position be guided by its parent. as far as I know it seems impossible to make a networkmanager instantiate a new player prefab and attach a camera afterwards on the same hierarchy level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However Now I am facing the problem where my camera rotation is also
>   affected by the rotation of my prefab parent

That's because your `Camera` is a child of the player so it will do whatever the Player/parent is doing.
Your camera should not be under the player. Remove it and make sure it is not a child of the Player or any other Object. That script should work or make the camera follow the player without making the `Camera` the child of the GameObject.

Remove  `Player = GameObject.Find ("Player");` from the `LateUpdate` function. You have already done this in the `Start` function, so it is unnecessary to do it in the `LateUpdate` function.  `GameObject.Find ("Player");` should never be called directly from the `LateUpdate` function. It will slow down your game.

EDIT:

After reading your comment, it looks like you want to instantiate a player with the camera. You can do this without making the camera a child of your player.

**Your current Setup**:

- Player

  - Model
  - Projectile

    - Projectile Mesh
  - Camera

So your camera is under Player.

**You new Setup**:

- PlayerPrefab

  - Player

    - Model
    - Projectile

      - Projectile Mesh
  - Camera (Attach script in question to this)

`Camera` is now **PlayerPrefab** instead of **Player**. Now, you can instantiate **PlayerPrefab** and move the **Player** with a script. I don't know what your move script looks like but it should be attached to the **Player** not **PlayerPrefab**. The **PlayerPrefab**  is used to hold everything so that it can be easily instantiated as one. The code in your question should be attached to your `Camera`.

Comment: I Did this in first place and it was actually working. I made an empty gameObject called playerContainer and added the camera to that one so that it was on the same hierarchy level as player. The problem I the faced was that I needed to access the "isLocalPlayer" property given from a network identity in player. since a networkidentity may appear only once in a prefab i needed to ad it to the container for the networkmanager to accept it as player prefab. So how would i access my "isLocalPlayer" property from somewhere lower in the hierarchy ?

Comment: @MarkStroeven Modified my answer that may solve your network problem. Read from EDIT down. Don't know much about networkidentity  but you can attach it to the `PlayerPrefab` which is the parent of all the prefabs.